# How to get element name in soap message using simplexml

Tags: php, web-services, soap, laravel-5, simplexml

Hi i'm trying to get the element name from these soap message so as to determine what action to be taken however  i get Body in this case accountInformationRequest is what I'm after .I am getting multiple requests on a single URL thus need to get the element name.These is what i have tried

```
 $xml=simplexml_load_string($content);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://www.yyy.com/mct/tx/2.0');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://www.yyy.com/mct/ty/2.0');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://www.yyy.com/mct/tx/2.1');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns3', 'http://www.yyy.com/mct/ty/2.1');

 $bodies = $xml->xpath('env:Body');
 foreach($bodies as $body){

    echo $body->getName();

        $reply = $body->children('ns', TRUE)->accountInformationRequest;
}




//Soap message
        <soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns="http://www.yyy.com/mct/tx/2.0" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.yyy.com/mct/ty/2.0"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.yyy.com/mct/tx/2.1"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.yyy.com/mct/ty/2.1">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:accountInformationRequest>
             <ns:security>
                <ns1:login>sam</ns1:login>
                <ns1:password>lin</ns1:password>
             </ns:security>
             <ns:hsTransactionId>001</ns:hsTransactionId>
             <ns:destinationUri>003</ns:destinationUri>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <ns:routingTag>B2B</ns:routingTag>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <ns2:vendorSpecificFields>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <ns3:vsf>
                   <ns3:vendorId>10</ns3:vendorId>
                   <ns3:fieldId>22</ns3:fieldId>
                   <ns3:value>2</ns3:value>
                </ns3:vsf>
             </ns2:vendorSpecificFields>
          </ns:accountInformationRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath specifically asks for elements with the name `Body` in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, so calling `getName()` on the elements it finds will always return the name "Body".

What you want to find is the name of the *child* of the body tag; you could either build this into the XPath, e.g. `->xpath('env:Body/*')`, or you could loop over the children of `$body`, e.g. `foreach ( $body->children('http://www.yyy.com/mct/tx/2.0') as $child ) { echo $child->getName(); }`